# Passing result of one DBIO into another

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm new to Slick and I am trying to rewrite the following two queries to work in one transaction. My goal is to
 1. check if elements exists
 2. return existing element or create it handling autoincrement from MySQL

The two functions are:

```
  def createEmail(email: String): DBIO[Email]  = {
    // We create a projection of just the email column, since we're not inserting a value for the id column
    (emails.map(p => p.email)
      returning emails.map(_.id)
      into ((email, id) => Email(id, email))
      ) += email
  }

  def findEmail(email: String): DBIO[Option[Email]] =
    emails.filter(_.email === email).result.headOption
```

How can I safely chain them, ie. to run first check for existence, return if object already exists and if it does not exist then create it and return the new element in one transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a for comprehension:

```
def findOrCreate(email: String) = {
  (for {
    found <- findEmail(email)
    em <- found match {
      case Some(e) => DBIO.successful(e)
      case None => createEmail(email)
    }
  } yield em).transactionally
}

val result = db.run(findOrCreate("batman@gotham.gov"))
// Future[Email]
```

Comment: And `db.run(findOrCreate("batman@gotham.gov").transactionally)` to run in one transaction.

Comment: @liosedhel: Updated.

Comment: Thx for your help! Side question - is there any way to access `e` in the pattern matching to peak under it's elements and pass them to `createEmail`? So that I can do eg. `createEmail(e.name)`

Comment: @Niemand: Sure. Just replace `DBIO.successful(e)` with `createEmail(e.name)`. Though I don't know why you would do that, since in that case an existing email is found.

Comment: @chunjef I need if for a bit more complicated query I pasted over there - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842992/slick-passing-results-between-multiple-queries-in-one-transaction

Answer (score 1):

With a little help of cats library:

```
def findOrCreate(email: String): DBIO[Email] = {
    OptionT(findEmail(email)).getOrElseF(createEmail(email)).transactionally
}
```